# How can i solve this errors in python django?

Tags: python, django

Hi im very novice at python django.

This is my django views.py codes

```
def post_list(request):
request.session['lat'] = request.POST['user_lat']
request.session['lon'] = request.POST['user_lon']
userpoint = GEOSGeometry('POINT('lat' 'lon')', srid=4326)
list_total = list_1
i=1
while i:
    list_i = Post.objects.filter(point_distance__lte = userpoint, D(km=i)
    list_total = 'list_total' + ',' + 'list_i')
    result_list = list(chain(list_total))
    if len(result_list) >= 50 :
        break

template = loader.get_template('blog/index.html')
context = {
    'post_list': post_list,
}

return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

First of all, I want make list to using request.session[]=request.POST[] to make coordinates and this coordinates will be used on my pointfield at 'model.py' is it possible? or is it has any problems?

And Second, in terminal(ubuntu16.04), i used python3 manage.py makemigrations command, it gave me messages as follows,
from codes like this,

```
request.session['lat'] = request.POST['user_lat']
request.session['lon'] = request.POST['user_lon']
userpoint = GEOSGeometry('POINT('lat' 'lon')', srid=4326)
```

error occured like this->

```
userpoint = GEOSGeometry('POINT('lat' 'lon')', srid=4326)
                                  ^
                               SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

from code like this ,

```
list_i = Post.objects.filter(point_distance__lte = userpoint, D(km='i'))
                                                                                                                ^
```

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

this SyntaxError occoured.

Last, from this code,

```
while i:
    list_i = Post.objects.filter(point_distance__lte = userpoint, D(km=i))
    list_total = 'list_total' + ',' + 'list_i')
    result_list = list(chain(list_total))
    if len(result_list) >= 50 :
        break
```

-> This SyntaxError occoured.

```
list_total = list_total + ',' + 'list_i'
         ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How can i solve this problems?

```
while i:
    list_i = Post.objects.filter(point_distance__lte = userpoint, D(km=i))
    list_total = 'list_total' + ',' + 'list_i')
    result_list = list(chain(list_total))
    if len(result_list) >= 50 :
        break
```

ps. I want make my own result_list using list(chain()) function, but i wonder it is valid.

itertools - python doc : https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html
i was according to GEOdjango codes : 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-lookups

Im using python3 (maybe 3.5) , django 1.9

thanks for reading my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not instantiate a GEOSGeometry object with that mis-formed string. Use

userpoint = GEOSGeometry('POINT('+ latvariable + ' ' + lonvariable +')', srid=4326)

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the closing backet at line:

```
list_i = Post.objects.filter(point_distance__lte = userpoint, D(km=i)
```

Comment: Thank you. But even after i added backet, 'SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument'  has been made at 'D(km=i) '. how can i solve it?

Comment: @touchingtwist list_i = Post.objects.filter(D(km=i), point_distance__lte = userpoint)